# When tests are run, an array containing the intersected strings from 2 other arrays wont display

Tags: c#

I was wondering if anyone can help!

My foreach loop doesnt get hit when tests run.

I think i have overlooked something but cannot see it.

Here is the class

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Challenge
{
    public static string[] FindIntersection(string[] first,string[] second)
    {
      var intersect = first.Intersect(second);
      
      string[] intersectArr = new string[1];
      
      foreach (string res in intersect) {
        intersectArr.Concat(new string[] {res}).ToArray();
        return intersectArr;
      }
      
      return null;
```

here is the test class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
[TestFixture]
public class FindIntersectionTest
{
  [Test]
  public void ShouldReturnAnEmptyArrayWhenNoElementsAreCommon()
  {
    Assert.AreEqual(new string[] {}, Challenge.FindIntersection(new string[] {"a","b"},new string[] {"c","d"}));
  }
  [Test]
  public void ShouldReturnTheCommonElementWhenThereIsOneElementInCommon()
  {
    Assert.AreEqual(new string[] {"a"}, Challenge.FindIntersection(new string[] {"a","b"},new string[] {"a","B"}));
  }
  [Test]
  public void ShouldReturnTheFirstThreeCommonElementsWhenThereAreMoreThanThreeElementsInCommon()
  {
    Assert.AreEqual(new string[] {"b","c","d"}, Challenge.FindIntersection(new string[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f"},new string[] {"e","d","c","b"}));
  }
}
```

the console output is

```
FindIntersectionTest
ShouldReturnAnEmptyArrayWhenNoElementsAreCommon
Test Failed
  Expected: <empty>
  But was:  null
Completed in 79.3480ms
ShouldReturnTheCommonElementWhenThereIsOneElementInCommon
Test Failed
  Expected and actual are both <System.String[1]>
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: "a"
  But was:  null
Completed in 6.9410ms
ShouldReturnTheFirstThreeCommonElementsWhenThereAreMoreThanThreeElementsInCommon
Test Failed
  Expected is <System.String[3]>, actual is <System.String[1]>
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: "b"
  But was:  null
```

I am not sure what to try to resolve this

Comment: You are using the `Intersect()` extension method from LINQ, but then do some additional `foreach()` action. Since you already use `Intersect()`, why not simply write `return first.Intersect(second).ToArray();`?

Answer (score 0):

`intersectArr.Concat(new string[] {res}).ToArray();` is here the Toarray create a copy and return.
Instead do like this

```
intersecArr = intersectArr.Concat(new string[] {res}).ToArray();
```

But what @Progman said in comment is better